# Directories break after loading framework in Polycode Xcode project

Tags: c++, xcode

I have what could be a very obvious problem when trying to load a framework in a Polycode (C++ gaming library) Xcode project.

I locate the framework in the file that its in, in finder. Then drag and drop into the Framework file in the left hand column in Xcode- a dialogue box comes up and I click ok. It's there in linked frameworks in the general tab, and in build phases. It's in the frameworks folder on the left. Press build and I get;

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/user/Documents/Polycode/Release/Darwin/Framework/Template/Xcode/../../Core/Lib"'

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/user/Documents/Polycode/Release/Darwin/Framework/Template/Xcode/../../Dependencies/Lib"'

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/user/Documents/Polycode/Release/Darwin/Framework/Template/Xcode/../../Core/Dependencies/lib"'

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Err, thats weird. I looked at the search paths and they were;

```
\"$(SRCROOT)/../../Core/Lib\"
\"$(SRCROOT)/../../Dependencies/Lib\"
\"$(SRCROOT)/../../Core/Dependencies/lib\"
/Users/user/Documents/Polycode/Release/Darwin/Framework/Modules/lib
```

I changed the first 3 back to what they must have been before I loaded the new framework, and now it builds fine. No idea why that would have changed! If anyone knows, please comment! Thanks.

Comment: I am having a similar problem trying to build the Polycode IDE and examples. I am assuming the first three look similar to the last one? These are settings you're changing in the project that is using Polycode, right?